# how can is delete all session information?

Tags: php, session

I'm getting ready to upgrade my website, and in the new update, there is the need for a new session variable user_level. I'm wondering if there is anyway server side that i can end all sessions without having to actually code anything. If not, my intention is to test whether or not the variable is set, and if it isn't i will destroy the session forcing the user to relog.
so something like this..

```
if(!$this->session->userdata['user_level']) 
{ 
    $this->session->sess_destroy(); 
}
```

Comment: I would personally do it with this approach as it would allow you to do things like warn the user that they need to log back in due to website upgrade.  If you took an alternate approach like just deleting all the session storage (in files or database), then you would not be able to give more user-friendly transition.

Comment: How would i delete the session storage out of curiosity? Also, my website is not to large. only 65ish users (even though i launched it today), so i don't think it would be that bad.

Answer (score 2):

`userdata` is a `function` not an `array` Read [Session docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Try this,

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('user_level')) 
{
    $this->session->userdata = array();
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
}
```

If you want to `unset a single session variable` then use it like,

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('user_level');// to remove user_level from session
```

Read http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/195025/

Comment: The problem isn't actually deleting the session. it's making sure that every user has the new variable, but I don't believe there is any way to automatically delete all sessions that the system has started correct???

Comment: @user2605381 test the above I've made changes in it.

Comment: wow. i've been accessing it as an array in all of my code.. :\ Why does it still work as an array then?

Comment: If you open `session library` then you will find that it is a `function` as well as an `array too`.